# How to fix Unhandled JS Exception and AppRegistry issue in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to replicate the TaxiApp tutorial in youtube by emancode using RN. I'm beginner in Javascript and RN, but I have more than 8 years experience in PHP - OOP.

1. I downloaded the latest version of RN and RN-CLI in my local machine.
2. I followed the instructions very well, and I even watched it thrice to check if I followed the code correctly.
3. I run it using react-native run-ios

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import { Router } from "react-native-router-flux";

import scenes from "../routes/scenes";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <Router scenes={scenes} />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Error 1. `Cannot read property 'object' of undefined`

Error 2. `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module`

RN version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8